# access object in object PHP

Tags: php, json, object

Could you help me to get access to the data of this object with PHP:

i'va tried to do how forum say to do  like :
echo $data->status->val->data;
but they told me :

Notice: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object
{
"status":true,
"val":{
"meta":{
"code":200,
"type":"Success",
"message":"Success"
},
"data":{
"items":[
{
"id":"7c2bb34d54c7a01d50d8ed74bd49ce47",
"tracking_number":"YT2003521266065328",
"carrier_code":"yunexpress",
"status":"delivered",
"original_country":"China",
"destination_country":"Australia",
"itemTimeLength":10,
"origin_info":{
"weblink":"http://www.yunexpress.com/",
"phone":"4000-2621-26",
"carrier_code":"yunexpress",
"trackinfo":[
{
"Date":"2020-03-13 11:27:43",
"StatusDescription":"Your parcel has been delivered and a signature obtained.",
"Details":"Canberra",
"checkpoint_status":"delivered"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-12 18:51:25",
"StatusDescription":"Your parcel is with a Fastway courier and ready for delivery.",
"Details":"Canberra",
"checkpoint_status":"pickup"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-09 14:31:50",
"StatusDescription":"delivery to local courier",
"Details":"SYDNEY - AUSTRALIA",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-09 14:30:45",
"StatusDescription":"Your parcel is being sorted for delivery. We\u2019ll update you when your parcel is on its way to the delivery destination.",
"Details":"Sydney",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-09 10:11:24",
"StatusDescription":"Your shipping information has been submitted to Fastway. Please allow at least 24 hours for the next update.",
"Details":"Sydney",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-09 09:33:50",
"StatusDescription":"Clearance processing complete at GATEWAY",
"Details":"SYDNEY - AUSTRALIA",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-06 20:37:00",
"StatusDescription":"Arrived at AIRPORT of Destination,Custom clearance in processing.",
"Details":"SYDNEY - AUSTRALIA",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-06 08:30:00",
"StatusDescription":"Departure from airport to destination country | HONG KONG INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT",
"Details":"HONG KONG - CHINA",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-05 19:00:13",
"StatusDescription":"Departed Facility In processing center",
"Details":"SHENZHEN",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-05 03:33:38",
"StatusDescription":"Shipment has been processed in operational center",
"Details":"SHENZHEN",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
},
{
"Date":"2020-03-04 02:22:18",
"StatusDescription":"Arrived at Sort Facility SHENZHEN",
"Details":"SHENZHEN",
"checkpoint_status":"transit",
"ItemNode":"ItemReceived"
},
{
"Date":"2020-02-04 13:22:03",
"StatusDescription":"Shipment information received",
"Details":"",
"checkpoint_status":"transit"
}
]
},
"destination_info":null
}
]
}
}
}

Comment: `$php_array = json_decode($json_string, true);`

Comment: It tell me : 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cashback_utils/package_tracker/ajax.php on line 47
Array